# How to solve a behavioural aspect when download speed is poor

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I am not sure how to phrase this question so I will just give the facts and the result.

I am using Web-sockets in my HTML5/JavaScript page.

This web-socket connection connects to my listening socket on my server hosted in a Windows Application.  The client says 'here i am to my server' and my server responds by send 5 jpegs in byte array format to this client every second.

These JPEGs are on average size 12KB.

I left this running for a couple of hours.

On my return I looked at my client and the animation has frozen to a crawl.

The time-stamp displayed in my client on those JPEGS are running 2 hours behind what has already been sent.

Now, I did an internet speed test on the client PC and it reports 0.51Mbp which is very slow.

So, the problems lies in the download speed that my test PC has access to.

It is using a wireless connection in a busy office environment.

The question is how to deal with this? After all these images will eventually get through to my client and as such is causing a backlog until the download speed improves.

The immediate solution I have is that once the image is received a single byte is sent back to my server to request the next image.  But, the reason I wanted to use web sockets in the 1st place is to be able to remove the duplex behaviour and avoid that 'ping' back to my server as I would deem it an unnecessary over-head.

Is there another approach to this?

Thanks

Comment: Have the server wait for its push to complete, then if the elapsed time is < 1 sec wait else send the next batch?

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion but my understanding is that the push happens asynchronously so it returns straight away?

Comment: Depends on how its implemented, even asynchronously there is likely a completion event of some description

Comment: Hi, well I could look into that but again, this is not a signal/event that the client has received a jpeg. Also, if it did will that not be a 'ping' back from the client?

Comment: Well the send would complete when all the data has been sent down the wire, i.e. received by the client, this would mean you would know that it was ready and able to process more data

Comment: yes, but that does nto solve the issue i have observed where the client is waiting for the jpeg. As soon as the bytes have left my server it will traverse from node to node along the internet/network. I need to find a way to handle a poor connection on the client without having to ping back..